# How to make particular sliders as a default slider in Slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am using **slider revolution** as my sliders in my wordpress project

I do have four sliders in the project . The screenshot is shown below
[image: Screenshots containing sliders]

As per current screnario i have **#3 Retrax video** as my default slider , I just want to change it to **#1 Main Slider.**

I could not able to find any option to change it.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In slider revolution you cannot define which slider should show as default slider on the website. This can be possible through theme.

There are two ways to set any slider as default slider.

1. Go to Appearance - > Theme Option -> (Find header or slider setting there to set any slider as default slider)
2. Go to Pages and select your page such as Home Page and then find option there to select slider as main slider.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I couldn't able to find slider settings

Comment: Can I have your website link and I will let you know where to add.

Answer (score -2):

**Updating Image/Video in Revolution Slider**

How to edit/update your slide(s) in Revolution Slider,

1. Login to your WordPress Admin and click on Revolution Slider at the left pane,then click on Edit Slides.
2. From the slides list, look for the specific image that you would like to change or update, then click on Edit Slide.
3. Under Slider Main Image / Background, select Image BG  then click on Change Image button.
4. Upload the file that you would like to add, then insert it.
5. Save it by clicking on the green square button at the right until it says “Slides updated“.
6. View your site online and see if the new image is showing already.

Get the More information, you can go through the link - https://www.jezweb.info/updating-image-in-revolution-slider/